# Symfony faker relationships

Tags: php, database, symfony, faker

Hello I come to see you because I have a little problem with faker and dataFixtures
in fact when I run the command to add the data bah I have an error in database because "region_id" is null
I share my code

```
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Advertisement;
use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\Region;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Faker\ORM\Doctrine\Populator;

class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $generator = \Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');

        $populator = new Populator($generator, $manager);
        $populator->addEntity(Advertisement::class, 200, [
            'address' => function() use ($generator) { return $generator->address; },
            'description' => $generator->text(2000),
            'price' => mt_getrandmax(),
            'imageName' => function() use ($generator) { return 'https://picsum.photos/1000/700'; },
            'imageName2' => function() use ($generator) { return 'https://picsum.photos/1000/700'; },
            'imageName3' => function() use ($generator) { return 'https://picsum.photos/1000/700'; },
            'imageName4' => function() use ($generator) { return 'https://picsum.photos/1000/700'; },
        ]);
        $populator->addEntity(User::class, 10);
        $populator->addEntity(Category::class, 5);
        $populator->execute();
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

and my entity Advertisement relation

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Region", inversedBy="advertisement")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="advertisement")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="advertisement")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $CreatedAt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CreatedAt = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
        $this->isValid = 0;
    }
```

My problem is that in database tells me the relations in null I do not understand why, if you have a solution or an idea I am a taker
Thank you for your help

Comment: I haven't used the Faker myself, but are just missing the Region entity addition as it is a mandatory reference to have for Advertisement entities? I.e. `$populator->addEntity(Region::class, 5);` or something like that

Comment: I have already done but it does not work either I do not understand why it's weird

Comment: other possible reason could be that you need to populate the entities in correct order for the Faker to pick up the existing entity ids: i.e. try creating the Region, User, and Category instances before the Advertisement instances.

Comment: it's working thank you for you help !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! <3